# Relacionado ou duplicata?

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

Estava analisando [**essa pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53129/14674), que estava marcada como duplicata, mas fiquei na dúvida, como o Bigown comentou.

O autor até mencionou o relacionamento com outra pergunta, que não é a que está sendo apontada como duplicata. Sendo assim eu pergunto:

Perguntas que pedem mais explicações sobre outra devem ser consideradas duplicatas?

Comment: A pergunta mencionada pelo AP não é a mesma da duplicata.

Comment: É verdade, vou atualizar a pergunta...

Comment: O AP pede mais explicações daquela pergunta, essas explicações podem estar noutra pergunta. Acho que sim, dependendo da pergunta pode ser considerada duplicata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu acho que é duplicata. Como o pessoal já comentou o pedido de mais explicações não é o problema. Pelo contrário. O problema é que as explicações específicas que ele pede já existem em uma terceira pergunta. Se a pegunta dele fosse considerada não duplicata e continuasse aberta eu iria responder basicamente com o conteúdo da outra porque acho que a outra tem tudo o que ele quer saber, senão a pergunta não está clara.

E olha que seria uma boa oportunidade para dar minha resposta sobre o assunto. Se eu desse na pergunta original da duplicata ela ficaria enterrada como outras boas ficaram. Na [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4731/101) eu considero as respostas do hugomg e do carlosraphaelgn excelentes complementos para a resposta aceita e deveria ter mais votos. Até a resposta do Math merecia mais votos.

Comment: O próprio autor da pergunta concorda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53129/troca-de-cadeias-de-if-switch-por-polimorfismo#comment109864_53129

Comment: "até a resposta do Math merecia mais votos" pegou pesado ein... kkkkkk