# O que fazer com publicações que dependem de algo que não existe mais?

Tags: debate, perguntas, respostas

O que fazemos com publicações que dependem diretamente de outra publicação, sendo que, cuja a referida não existe mais ou foi removida?

Um exemplo é essa pergunta aqui no SOpt-meta: [Relacionado ou duplicata?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2534/relacionado-ou-duplicata?rq=1)

Têm mais exemplos mas eu não consigo listar todos.

Minha dúvida é diretamente relacionada ao SOpt-meta, mas isto pode acontecer também com perguntas no SOpt que perguntam sobre uma determinada documentação no passado que hoje mudou muito, ou não existe.

O que fazemos com estas perguntas, respostas, publicações em geral, cujo dependem diretamente de uma origem que já não existe mais para ter coesão?

Comment: Acho que já está errado uma pergunta depender integralmente de outra. É interessante, sim, citar a pergunta que originou a nova discussão, mas essa deve apresentar em seu corpo um resumo completo do contexto presente na pergunta original de forma que sejam independentes.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu sempre cito em minhas referências o que estou vinculando doutra origem, seja uma pergunta, resposta ou qualquer publicação externa, como um livro por exemplo. Mas a citação `>` nem sempre é utilizada e quando é, é usada de forma errônea.

Comment: Eu não sei se consegui entender, mas se o link for vital mesmo (o que acredito que muitas vezes não seja, pq acredito que o site seja uma forma de agregar conhecimento tanto na resposta quanto na pergunta, mas não vou entrar em debate sobre isto) você pode usar o https://archive.org/web/, devo dizer que tem diversos exemplos nos SOs, METAs, assim como no Metão, aonde links expiraram e posteriormente o AP (ou outra pessoa) editou colocando o link vindo do archive.org

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento alguns links não são encontrados no Wayback. [Exemplo](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53129/troca-de-cadeias-de-if-switch-por-polimorfismo).

Comment: @CypherPotato não tem como o Wayback indexar tudo com tanta eficiência, eles indexam o que é possivel dentro de um tempo razoável, mas como eu disse, apesar de querer evitar sobre isto, creio que muitas vezes os links são desnecessários, você tendo o score necessário para ler perguntas e respostas deletadas você pode absorver o que é contido nelas e levar para a nova postagem.